Existing Swift App return to React Native
An application written in Swift is currently live on the app store. I want to rewrite this application from scratch using react native. However, can I release an update to the app store for the existing app written in Swift instead of publishing a new app? I want to replace the existing app rather than sharing a new one. Is such a thing possible? Moreover is the same way be valid Play Store

Yes it’s possible.

Yes and Yes. App store and Play Store do not care how your app was developed or the language, you can update your app with a new written app in another framework
